# React Navigation v6 Drawer blank screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation-v6

I am creating a mobile app using React Native, and I have ended up using react-navigation v6 for creating a drawer navigator in the Dashboard of my app. The Dashboard is only displayed when the user is logged, while the Login screen is shown when the user is not logged.

I want to add a drawer on the Dashboard, and to open it using a button on the top bar of the Dashboard. I have a `DashboardScreens` component that was only rendering the Dashboard component like this: `return <Dashboard />;`. What I did for creating the drawer was to **import** `createDrawerNavigator` from `'@react-navigation/drawer'` and `NavigationContainer` from `'@react-navigation/native'`. Now, the returned JSX from `DashboardScreens` looks like this:

```
         <NavigationContainer>
            <MenuNav.Navigator
                initialRouteName="Dashboard"
            >
                <MenuNav.Screen name="Dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
            </MenuNav.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
```

The creation of the navigator was done above the definition of the `DashboardScreens`, through this line: `const MenuNav = createDrawerNavigator();`

However, all I get now is a blank screen.

[image]